# A question regarding an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be an equilateral triangle such that the length of its side is $a$. Let $X$ be a point on the side $AB$ such that distance from $A$ to $X$ is $a/3$ and similarly $Y$ is a point on side $BC$ such that distance from $B$ to $Y$ is $a/3$.

Let $T$ be the intersection of lines $AY$ and $CX$. What is the size of the angle $\angle CTB$?

I should use only geometry(similar and congruent triangles and such), so no trigonometry.

My comments: Obviously, the triangles $ABY$ and $AXC$ are congruent. Also, triangles $AXT$ and $ABY$ are similar. Also (not sure about this) I managed to get that the angle $\angle CTY$ equals $60$ degrees.

I'm not sure how to progress further. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $\angle CTY$ is $60^\circ$, then shouldn't $\angle xTA$ also be $60^\circ$? Thus, since $\angle CTY+ \angle xTA + \angle ATC + \angle xTy = 360$, then $ \angle ATC + \angle xTy = 360 - 120 = 240$. Then each angle, $\angle ATC $ and $\angle xTy$, equals $\frac{240}{2}=120^\circ$.

Comment: Place a similar point on AC called Z whereby you create a smaller equilateral triangle. Angle CTY is indeed 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted no trigonometry at all?

Let $B'$ be the reflection of $B$ across Y, and realize $BXB'$ is equaliteral. Note that $\triangle ATX \sim \triangle ABY$ , so $\angle CTY = \angle ATX = \angle ABY = 60^\circ$. Note, this implies that quadrilateral $XTYB$ is cyclic, so $\angle YTB = \angle YXB$. But $XY$ is the median of $BXB'$, so it is also the angle bisector, and thus $\angle YXB= 30^\circ$. The result is

$$\angle CTB = \angle CTY + \angle YTB = 90^\circ$$

Comment: Your previous answer was great as well. Thanks, man.