# Alternative methods of solving an angle in an equilateral triangle

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, solution-verification

This question has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2756259/721644), but the OP said trigonometry was forbidden. I was thinking of different approaches that allow trigonometry, so I decided to post a new question.

> An equilateral triangle is given with edges of the length $a$. Let $X\in\overline{AB}$ s.t. $|AX|=\frac{a}{3}$ and let $Y\in\overline{BC}$ s.t. $|BY|=\frac{a}{3}$. Let $T$ be the intersection point of $AY$ and $CX$. Find $\measuredangle{CTB}$.

First of all, $|BX|=2|BY|\;\&\;\measuredangle XBC=60^{\circ}\implies\Delta XBY$ is one half of an equilateral triangle$\implies\measuredangle BYX=90^{\circ}\implies\color{red}{\Delta XYC\;\text{is a right-triangle}}$.

Now, $|XY|^2=\left(\frac{2a}{3}\right)^2-\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)^2=\frac{3a^2}{9}$

$|CX|=\sqrt{|XY|^2+|YC|^2}=\frac{\sqrt{7}a}{3}$

According to the $SAS$ *(Side-Angle-Side)* theorem, $\Delta ABY\cong\Delta AXC\;\&\;\Delta XBC\cong\Delta AYC$.
Then,

$\measuredangle CXB=\measuredangle AYC\;\&\;\measuredangle YCT=\measuredangle BCX\implies\measuredangle CTY=\measuredangle XBC=60^{\circ}\implies\Delta TYC\sim\Delta BCX$
$$\implies\frac{|XC|}{|YC|}=\frac{|BC|}{|CT|}\implies|CT|=\frac{|BC|\cdot|YC|}{|XC|}=\frac{a\frac{2a}{3}}{\frac{\sqrt{7}a}{3}}=\frac{2a}{\sqrt{7}}$$

In $\Delta XYC$, we have:$\cos(\measuredangle YCX)=\frac{|CY|}{|CX|}=\frac{\frac{2a}{3}}{\frac{\sqrt{7}a}{3}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{7}}$

In $\Delta BCT$, we have:
$$|BT|=\sqrt{|BC|^2+|CT|^2-2|BC|\dot|CT|\cos(\measuredangle YCX)}=\sqrt{a^2+\frac{4a^2}{7}-2a\cdot\frac{2a}{\sqrt{7}}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{7}}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{\sqrt{7}}$$

In $\Delta YCT$, we have: $\frac{|CY|}{\sin(\measuredangle CTY)}=\frac{|CT|}{\sin(\measuredangle TYC)}\implies \sin(\measuredangle TYC)=\frac{|CT|\sin(\measuredangle CTY)}{|CY|}=\frac{\frac{2a}{\sqrt{7}}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{\frac{2a}{3}}=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{7}}=\sin(\measuredangle BYT)$

In $\Delta BYT$, we have $\frac{|BT|}{\sin(\measuredangle BYT)}=\frac{|BY|}{\sin(\measuredangle YTB)}\implies\measuredangle YTB=\arcsin\frac{|BY|\sin(\measuredangle BYT)}{|BT|}=\arcsin\frac{\frac{a}{3}\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{7}}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{\sqrt{7}}}=\arcsin\frac{1}{2}\implies\measuredangle YTB=30^{\circ}$

Finally, $\measuredangle CTB=\measuredangle TYB+\measuredangle CTY=90^{\circ}$

Picture:[image]

**My question is**: is there any shorter way I could solve this via trigonometry or vectors? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof with vectors. Assume $|{AB}|=|{BC}|=|{CA}|=1$. Then, 
$$\vec {AB}\cdot \vec {AC} = \vec {BC}\cdot \vec {BA}=\vec {CA}\cdot \vec {CB}=\cos60^\circ=\frac12\tag1$$
Given that
$$\frac{|XT|}{|CT|}=\frac{Area_{AXY}}{Area_{ACY}}=\frac{\frac13\cdot\frac13Area_{ABC}}{\frac23Area_{ABC}}=\frac16\implies\frac{|CT|}{|CX|} =\frac67$$

and $\vec {CX} = \frac13 \vec {AB} - \vec {AC}$, we have

$$\vec {BT} = \vec {CT} - \vec {CB}=\frac67 \vec {CX} - \vec {CB}
= \frac67 \left(\frac13\vec {AB} - \vec {AC} \right)- \vec {CB}$$

Evaluate

$$\vec {BT}\cdot \vec {CX} = \left(\frac27 \vec {AB} - \frac67\vec {AC} - \vec {CB}\right)\cdot \left( \frac13 \vec {AB} - \vec {AC}\right)=0$$

where the doc-products in (1) are used. Thus, $\angle CTB = 90^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

Not a trigonometric solution, but I decided to post it anyway.

It is clear that triangles $CXA$ and $AYB$ are congruent, hence $\angle CXA=\angle AYB$. Hence quadrilateral $BXTY$ is cyclic. The center of this circle is the midpoint $M$ of $XB$ as $MB=MX=\frac 13 a=MY$. Hence $\angle BTY =\frac 12 \angle BMY = 30^\circ$.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but that already is in the thread.

Comment: Oh, I forgot what the question was. I thought you asked about angle BTY, not BTC. In that case it is even easier. Once you know that BXTY is cyclic and BYX is right then you get that BTX is right, hence CTB is right.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't even look at the link in the first sentence of your question. I'll delete this answer soon.

Comment: You don' t have to. Since the post has been inactive, it will be useful to future readers.